# Is it correct that git fetch gets info about all remote branches and git pull does git fetch then only merges current branch?

Tags: git

Question in the topic essentially says it all.

It seems like under typical/default operation (multiple remote branches, multiple local branches, some of which may be tracking) that the `git fetch` operation will get information from the remote about all remote branches and load this into the local remote branch refs and that the `git pull` operation first performs a `git fetch` (which gets info about all remote branches) but then only merges in the remote branch which is tracked by the *currently checked out* local branch. Is this correct?

Comment: Sure. If pull affected _all_ local branches, how often would you use it? Needles to bring up the issue of `what about if there are conflicts on the other branches?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The reason is that `git merge` can only operate on the *current commit* (and hence the current branch, if there is a current branch at all—i.e., if you're not in "detached HEAD" mode).  If the merge succeeds, Git *could* go on to try more (local) branches with any updated upstreams, but it does not do so.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, merge is an action between the current commit and some other commit specified by a reference somewhere else (such as the remote branch). I was imaging something like merging together the tips of each tracking branch with its respective remote branch but that's complicated and not the desired effect. thank you.